# laravel blank white screen and no error message

Tags: laravel-5

I keep on getting blank white screen on my  project when routing some files with no error message. I have tried to clear routes, cache,views, and config using the artisan command with no effect.

Comment: Any assistance will highly be appreciated

Comment: You should describe if this is from the start, after doing something, if you have enabled debug etc.

Comment: go to config/app.php           and check 'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', ture),

Comment: @ThomasMoors It just happen that after working on the project for quite something, I realize that when I add some more routes, it just displays white blank screen.

Comment: @GauravGupta I have tried to change it from false to true but still same problem persists.

Comment: did you check your env also?

Comment: @GauravGupta I have just deleted the .env and copy the .env.example and rename it to .env. I have also done artisan key:generate but still there is no change

Comment: This worked for me after renaming the routes. Incredible!

Answer (score 0):

Change Your php version to 7.2